# Responsive web design and database access

Tags: sql-server, angularjs

I am new to both responsive web design and angular and I am working on building a web page that will access database and display things based on data in one of the SQL Server tables. Could someone please point me in the right direction of what can i use to grab data from the database? Do I need a web service? data component? what technology would be best to use?

Comment: Pretty much any server-side web development technology can be used to access a database.

Comment: This is both primarily opinion based and entirely too long for an online forum. Pick a technology and come back if you have questions about implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the responsive aspect, you can use simple CSS, media queries or any library designed for this purpose (like Twitter-bootstrap for example).

AngularJS won't access database directly since it's a client-side language. You will need to build a server-side application to access the database. Then, your Angular components can call your server-side application to retrieve data.
AngularJS modules + any-technology web-service can be a suitable solution.

The choice of a technology over another highly depends on your needs and constraints. Unless you can ask more precise questions, we cannnot help so much.

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for. How can I call, say .NET component that accesses database using AngularJS?

Comment: Your .NET component will access database when called, by an HTTP request for example. Your server-side application doesn't depend on AngularJS. Here how it works : AngularJS send a request on a specific URL. On the server-side application, this URL is mapped to a service which returns a HTTP response containing data. The Angular module will get this response back, like any web browser could have done calling the same URL with the same parameters.

Comment: so it should be a web service that accesses the database?

Comment: Yes. A web service is a form of server-side application :-)